# Angular building library error when using own library in library i am building

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

I am trying to build a library in which I am using in one of my own libraries. However it gives an error on the components that I export from the library I am using in the new library. I have no clue on how to solve this.

Full Error:

> ```
> ERROR: ecarelib/ecarelib.ts(29,17): Error during template compile of 'EcareLibModule'
> Function expressions are not supported in decorators Consider changing the function
> expression into an exported function.
> Cannot determine the module for class EcareLibComponent in
> C:/Users/ArneVandenEynden/vitalsigns/Ecare.VitalSigns.Client/node_modules/ecarelib/ecarelib.d.ts!
> Add EcareLibComponent to the NgModule to fix it.
> Cannot determine the module for class DossierComponent in
> C:/Users/ArneVandenEynden/vitalsigns/Ecare.VitalSigns.Client/node_modules/ecarelib/ecarelib.d.ts!
> Add DossierComponent to the NgModule to fix it.
> Cannot determine the module for class DossierListComponent in
> C:/Users/ArneVandenEynden/vitalsigns/Ecare.VitalSigns.Client/node_modules/ecarelib/ecarelib.d.ts!
> Add DossierListComponent to the NgModule to fix it.
> Cannot determine the module for class LoginComponent in
> C:/Users/ArneVandenEynden/vitalsigns/Ecare.VitalSigns.Client/node_modules/ecarelib/ecarelib.d.ts!
> Add LoginComponent to the NgModule to fix it.
> ```

Library i am using MODULE:

```
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders ,APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';
import { EcareLibComponent } from './ecarelib.component';
import { DossierComponent } from './dossier/dossier.component';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { DossierListComponent } from './dossier-list/dossier-list.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { SecurityInterceptor } from './security.interceptor';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppConfigService } from './services/app-config.service';
import { AuthenticateService } from './services/authenticate.service';

// @dynamic
@NgModule({
  declarations: [EcareLibComponent, DossierComponent, DossierListComponent, LoginComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: SecurityInterceptor,
    multi: true
  },{
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    multi: true,
    deps: [AppConfigService],
    useFactory: (appConfigService: AppConfigService) => {
      return () => {
        appConfigService.loadAppConfig();
      }
    }
  }],
  exports: [EcareLibComponent, DossierComponent, DossierListComponent, LoginComponent]
})
export class EcareLibModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: EcareLibModule,
      providers: [ AppConfigService, AuthenticateService]
    };
  }
}
```

Library i am building MODULE:

````
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { VitalsignsComponent } from './vitalsigns.component';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { ModalInputComponent } from './modal-input/modal-input.component';
import { VitalSignLinesListComponent } from './vital-sign-lines-list/vital-sign-lines-list.component';
import { NgSelectModule } from '@ng-select/ng-select';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { EcareLibModule } from 'ecarelib'
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { ComboBoxComponent } from './combo-box/combo-box.component';
import { ComboBoxPipe } from './combo-box/combo-box.pipe';
import { LogService } from './services/log.service';
import { ClickOutsideDirective } from './vital-sign-lines-list/click-outside.directive';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'modal', component: ModalInputComponent },
  { path: 'vitalSignLinesList', component: VitalSignLinesListComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    VitalsignsComponent,
    ModalInputComponent,
    VitalSignLinesListComponent,
    ComboBoxComponent,
    ComboBoxPipe,
    ClickOutsideDirective
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    EcareLibModule.forRoot(),
    NgSelectModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { enableTracing: false }),
    FormsModule,
    NgbModule
  ],
  providers: [LogService],
  exports: [VitalsignsComponent, VitalSignLinesListComponent]
})
export class VitalsignsModule {

}
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on the error it says

> Error during template compile of 'EcareLibModule' Function expressions
>   are not supported in decorators Consider changing the function
>   expression into an exported function.

So consider making your `useFactory` value to an exported function

```
providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: SecurityInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }, {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      multi: true,
      deps: [AppConfigService],
      useFactory: LoadAppConfig
    }],
  exports: [EcareLibComponent, DossierComponent, DossierListComponent, LoginComponent]
})
export class EcareLibModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: EcareLibModule,
      providers: [AppConfigService, AuthenticateService]
    };
  }
}


export function LoadAppConfig(appConfigService: AppConfigService) {
  return () => appConfigService.loadAppConfig();
}
```